# Trigger click works, but keyup does not work?

Tags: jquery

I have some dynamically generated textboxes with ids from `1000` to `1050`. If I want to click in one textbox it works:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  var jaas = parseInt(1000 + i); 
  $(document).on('click', '#' + jaas, function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
}
```

However when I change to the `keyup` event to detect 'enter' presses, it does not work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  var jaas = parseInt(1000 + i); 
  $(document).on('keyup', '#' + jaas, function () {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      alert($(this).val());
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What you have should work. Please check the console for errors elsewhere in your code. Also note that this is a really, really bad way of doing what you need. Instead, put a common class on all the elements and then add the event handler to that, eg `$(document).on('keyup', '.yourClass', function() { ...`

Comment: event.keyCode is deprecated.  Have you tried using event.which?
https://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Comment: Change function () into function (e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned e.which in a comment to your original question, and then promptly noticed you aren't actually providing a parameter for the event object in your callback.  Notice the function(**e**)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  var jaas = parseInt(1000 + i); 
  $(document).on('keyup', '#' + jaas, function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      alert($(this).val());
    }
  });
}
```